# Try with resources with multiple resources

Tags: java, file, io, try-with-resources

I am trying to use try-with-resources with the code below

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fileIn = new FileOutputStream("veri.obj");
    ObjectOutputStream objectIn = new ObjectOutputStream(fileIn);

    objectIn.writeObject("123"); 
    fileIn.close();
} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Like this,

```
try(FileOutputStream fileIn = new FileOutputStream("veri.obj");
    ObjectOutputStream objectIn = new ObjectOutputStream(fileIn))
{

    objectIn.writeObject("123"); 
} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I’m taking an IOException during writeObject();
The file is exist and there is no problem with r/w permission. The first code is running but second one is not. What am I missing?

I tried to check file existence and permission with methods of File class

Comment: [But I’m taking an IOException during writeObject();](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/17-errors)

Comment: Serialized Java objects are brittle and you should always try to avoid using ObjectOutputStream and ObjectWriter. And in your case it's entirely unnecessary! Use use a plain OutputStream. Better yet, use a FileWriter, as FileWriter has capacities for setting the serialized text charset (ie utf-8, etc)

Comment: *Better yet, use a FileWriter* Definitely not. Java serialization is a binary operation and unsuitable for treatment as a textual operation. It might be different if *textual serialization* were being used, but it isn't

Comment: First of all, you should decide whether you want to read or write data. You mixture of “in” and “out” in the identifiers should already scream at you that there’s something wrong. For `FileOutputStream`, it doesn’t matter whether the file exists. And contrary to the reading of objects, writing objects never throws `ClassNotFoundException` and therefore, this code doesn’t even pass the compiler. And your first variant which closes the `FileOutputStream` but not the `ObjectOutputStream` is broken and will created corrupted files (once you fix the compiler error).

Comment: What is the exception message? BTW you should have `objectIn.close();` not `fileIn.close();`